# What is the correct way to reference an image in an asp.net mvc 4 project?

Tags: image, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have image references that look like this: `src="../../Images/backup5.jpg"`. This matches the project structure. Although in the published version, these links do not work. If i change the path to `src="../Images/backup5.jpg"`  by removing a "../"  the image will display correctly. What is the correct way to reference these images so they work in both the development version and in the published version?

Follow up, how should this look when used in css as a `background:` attribute?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be using the [`Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) helper with the tilda [`~`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) marker (which resolves to the root of the application):

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Images/backup5.jpg")"
```

Comment: How would I use this in the background attribute in css? I have tried variations of this and can't quite get it to work.

Comment: @MattRockwell - CSS files are _static_ content and don't support server side code. The processing of CSS also takes the file location and relative paths into consideration, so you don't have to do this. Simply use a URL relative to the CSS file location.

Comment: @MattRockwell in css you're likely fine to use  `/Images/backup5.jpg` (as long as the Images folder is under the root of your domain ex: www.yourdomain.com/Images)

Comment: @mdmullinax for whatever reason neither of these seem to be working correctly on the server side version

Comment: @MattRockwell - Where are the images relative to the CSS file? Are you certain the CSS file is not cached on the browser (`Ctrl + F5` will refetch from server in most browsers)?

Comment: they are ../Images from the css file, yes I have been refreshing the cache.

Comment: @MattRockwell - Then that's what you need to use in the CSS file - `../Images/backup5.jpg`

Comment: The images work everywhere except for in IE9, if that makes a difference at all.

Comment: I figured it out! IE forces local sites to view in compatability mode. So if I put this into the header <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=emulateie9" /> it fixes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try `src="@Url.Content("~/Images/backup5.jpg")"`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Url.Content("~/Images/backup5.jpg")` Seems like a decent way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of those who are not working on an MVC project, they can use:

```
<img src="../Images/yourImage.png" height="yourHeight" width="yourWidth"/>
```

where `Images` is a new folder added to the existing project and `yourImage.png` can be added to that folder by doing right-hand click on the `Images` folder, selecting `Add` and then `Existing item`, and navigating to where the file is stored.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/trash.svg")">  OR 
<img src='/images/trash.svg'>
```