# How define the img src path in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have my index.cshtml with a image

> < img id="u3430_img" src="Images/send.png">

And a folder Images inside `myApp/Images` folder

if i access

- http:/localhost/myApp  OR
- http:/localhost/myApp/home/

works Ok. But if i use

- http:/localhost/myApp/home/index

The page try to look for the image in

- http:/localhost/myApp/**home**/Images/send.png

So how I should define my src.

**Aditional note:**
Beside the index.cshtml I also have an js file where a hover effect is add it to the image. And have same problem neither of those option work

```
$('#u3430_img').hover(
        function () {                
            $(this).attr("src", "~/Images/send_hover.png");
        },
        function () {                
            $(this).attr("src", "Images/send.png");
        }
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reference images in the top level of the project with the `~`.

```
<img src="~/Images/send.png">
```

Older versions of ASP.NET MVC needed a @Url.Content() around the path, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988322/what-is-the-correct-way-to-reference-an-image-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-project)

Edit: If you want to update the path from Javascript, you can either specify an absolute path, or wrap it in `@Url.Content()`.

```
$('#image').attr('src', '/Images/send.jpg');

$('#image').attr('src', '@Url.Content("~/Images/send.png")');
```

Comment: but what about inside a Javascript. I try to change the src by JQuey and got `http://localhost/myApp/~/Images/send.png`

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code? Usually if I'm specifying files inside a css file or something, I'll use a relative path (ex: ../images/send.png) if it's a file in ~/Content or something

Comment: Updated with the fix for javascript

Comment: I guess i will have to go for option number 1. Because option 2 doesnt seem to work if script is in a separated js file. Doesnt recognize the Razor code.

Comment: I think option 1 is better anyway, since you're not tying it to Razor. My understanding of MVC path resolution is to usually just try variations of /, ~/, and ../ until it works.

Answer (score 0):

in Cshtml page adding ~ is not necessary.Just add /Images/send.png  ...It will come to root and follow hierarchy.