# Display image in front end in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, the image path is stored in the database and server folder (image) but not displayed on the front.

Images are shown like this:

[image][image]

I was trying to display the image on the front in ASP.NET MVC.

I also attached the code of the controller and view to display the image using the Entity Framework model

In my controller method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Personaltable p, Personal u)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(u.AttachPicture.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(u.AttachPicture.FileName);
        filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        u.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + filename;
        filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), filename);
        u.AttachPicture.SaveAs(filename);

        using (PersonaltableEntities entity = new PersonaltableEntities())
        {
            var t = new Personaltable()//Make Variable of Table 
            {
                AttachPicture=SaveToPhysicalLocation(u.AttachPicture),

                LastPayCertificate = SaveToPhysicalLocation(u.LastPayCertificate)
            };

            db.Personaltables.Add(t);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch()
    {}
}

private string SaveToPhysicalLocation(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        return path;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

This is the view Controller on which I only show the image uploaded by the user in a list form.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{      
    return View(db.Personaltables.ToList());
}
```

This is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>  <td><img src="~/Image/" width="100",height="250"/></td></td>
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text and we can't use it to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add the data model code that used to pass the image source in the `<img>`  tag, please. Your screenshot above doesn't define the image filename - it  includes only folder name. It is necessary to specify the image file name in the `src` attribute.

Comment: See the following post: [How define the img src path in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29173165/6630084)

Comment: I Tried it but it's not working.

Comment: The image folder stores all the images but is not displayed on the front.

Comment: You still not included all code related to your question. **1)** Show more code of the view that includes the `<img>` tag and call to the `public ActionResult Create(Personaltable p, Personal u)` action method. **2)** Show action method that renders your view with the `<img>` tag. **3)** Take to account that code performing in the `Create()` action method is running on the server and the `@foreach (var item in Model)` loop also performing on the server environment, not a client side.

Comment: **4)** Why you doing this manipulation to the file name: `filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension`? Do you have a few files this the same name?

Comment: `<tr>  <td><img src="~/Image/" width="100",height="250"/></td></td>` - at least two errors on this line. First, you are just pointing your image tag to "~/Image/" _directory_ - while you should point to the actual _file_. You didn't specify the Model format here, so can't say for sure, but if it just contains a simple `List<string>` with image URLs, it will be `"~/Image/@{item}"`. Second, you are closing `<td>` tag twice and don't close `<tr>` at all - probably the second `</td>` should be `</tr>`.

Comment: Image is the folder in which ALL the images are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You must write src="~/Image/@item.ImagePath"

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>  <td><img src="~/Image/(????)" width="100",height="250"/></td></td>
}
```